# Out of office rules not working if TO filed contain group in the rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2010, out-of-office

If one of our users is going on holiday they need to check in the out of office function in the outlook. In the outlook there is a rule editor in the Auto-reply. In the upper side in this editor there is a FROM and TO filed.

So I would like to achieved the following:

1. If someone send and e-mail directly to this mailbox than the sender got an e-mail with the out of office message.  - Its ok.
2. If someone send and e-mail to a group which group is contain the users who went to vacation, than forward the e-mail to an address.

   So I set the Group in the TO filed in the Auto-reply rules editor and set an e-mail address to the Forward action in the editor. Unfortunately this not working.

   But if I set the user e-mail address TO filed, or pick the "directly for me" than the forward rule working.

Any idea why not working the GROUP in the TO field?